# .jpg to .pdf conversion in windows phone 8 app

Tags: image, pdf

I have started creating windows phone 8 app and captured an image (.jpg) file,  now I want to convert this .jpg file in to .pdf file.
Is there any way to do this ?

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know that windows app support winrt .winmd files only and normal dll doesnt work in window apps. So you would need the pdf sdk for rendering a pdf and add image to it. In Aspnet application Itextsharp dll is free sdk to support it but there are lot of paid sdk available  [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDFPhone/).But there are free sdks like [SilverPdf](http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/), [itextsharp custom](http://itextsharpsl.codeplex.com/discussions/430995). or try to create new one Or you can extend to Web api service by using service (post api) with image encoded in byte array and in serverside using free tools like the itextsharp you can generate it as pdf and return it to windows app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this out and let you know the result.Thanks again :)