# .jpg to .pdf Conversion - iTextSharp.text.PageSize' threw an exception in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8.1, itext

I am trying convert .jpg file to PDF using iTextSharp Library.

See my code below:

```
 using (MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());                    
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, newStream);
     writer.CloseStream = false;

     byte[] all = newStream.ToArray();
 }
```

But, I am getting error in this line:

```
Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

I am getting error like this:

> Message = "The type initializer for 'iTextSharp.text.PageSize' threw
>   an exception." InnerException = {System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=1.0.5000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How to deal with this, please suggest me.
Thanks!!

Comment: this post may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827669/jpg-to-pdf-conversion-in-windows-phone-8-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the way. I have added ComponentOne Library in Windows Phone 8.1 Project.

```
using C1.Phone.Pdf;
using C1.Phone.PdfViewer;

C1PdfDocument pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated);
pdf.Landscape = true;

var rc = new System.Windows.Rect(20,30,300,200);
pdf.DrawImage(wbitmp, rc);

var fillingName = "Test.pdf";
var gettingFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var loadingFinalStream = gettingFile.CreateFile(fillingName))
{
   pdf.Save(loadingFinalStream);
}
```

Comment: how that works? it didn't work for me? is that silverlight or rt?

Comment: @Amin yes it is silverlight dude!!

Answer (score 1):

iTextsharp does not (yet) support windows phone. One of the problems that you are experiencing is that System.Drawaing doesn't exist in windows phone but it would fail some place else. There's a list of windows phone supported assemblies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Can the version of iTextSharp without `System.Drawing` be used?

Comment: So,  nothing to use it!! Damn windows phone!! Thanx @Paulo

Comment: @ChrisHaas: It's not only System.Drawing, all the file management would have to be changed and many other parts.